# How to undo the wrong commit and update it back in git

Tags: git, commit

I have been using git commands for my project.

1. If I made one wrong commit and pushed into my branch. On that time, how can I update it back ?
2. If I need to copy last three commits to new branch, how can I do?

Need programmers help soon... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

#### A1. You should `reset` and `push -f`.

Now situation.

```
A - B - C - D ← HEAD and wrong commit
```

You should rollback HEAD.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

now

```
A - B - C ← HEAD
```

finally, you should force push to your remote repository.

```
git push origin your_branch -f
```

#### A2. use `cherry-pick`

Now situation.

```
        need to copy
       |---------|
A - B - C - D - E← old branch
 \
  F - G - H ← new branch
```

use `cherry-pick` on your new branch

```
git cherry-pick <C commit hash>
git cherry-pick <D commit hash>
git cherry-pick <E commit hash>
```

now

```
A - B - C - D - E← old branch
 \
  F - G - H - C' - D' - E'← new branch
```

Answer (score 2):

To revert your faulty commit, simply use `git revert` and push that.

It's not going to remove it from the project history, though.  For that you'd need to locally rewrite said history, and push that; but many upstream repositories prevent that since it messes up everyone else-s workflow.

To copy the three last commits from a branch `feature` to your current branch, use the following:

```
git cherry-pick feature~3..feature
```

Comment: what is cherry-pick here ? like github ?